How to handle dynamic data updates in an offline React app?
I'm using RTK Query to fetch data from a REST API in my React app. To improve offline capabilities, I want to cache data using both IndexedDB and Cache Storage. How can I effectively handle dynamic data updates, ensuring consistency between online and offline states? I'm considering using background sync to synchronize local data when the network becomes available.
Implementing a basic IndexedDB store for local data storage and using a manual synchronization mechanism.
import { openDB } from 'idb';

const addStaticData = async () => {
    try {
        const db = await openDB('myDatabase', 1, {
            upgrade(db) {
                if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('myStore')) {
                    const store = db.createObjectStore('myStore', { keyPath: 'id' });
                    store.createIndex('name', 'name');
                }
            },
        });

const tx = db.transaction('myStore', 'readwrite');
    const store = tx.objectStore('myStore');

    const staticData = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Item 1', value: 'Static Data 1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Item 2', value: 'Static Data 2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Item 3', value: 'Static Data 3' },
    ];

    for (const item of staticData) {
        await store.put(item);
        console.log('Added item:', item); // Debugging log
    }

    await tx.done;
    console.log('Static data added successfully.');
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to add static data:', error);
}
};

declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    console.log('Service worker installed');
});
self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    console.log('Service worker activated');
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event: FetchEvent) => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then((cachedResponse) => {
                if (cachedResponse) {
                    return cachedResponse;
                }
                return fetch(event.request);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Fetch failed:', error);
                return new Response('Network error occurred', { status: 500 });
            })
    );
});


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
